# Unexpected behavior when calling super().__repr__() on a subclass of set?

Tags: python, repr

**See edit below for an explanation of this behavior (in CPython)**

In Python 3.9.5, I'm creating two custom collection types, one inheriting from `list` and the other from `set`.  I want them to have custom `__repr__` methods.  Simple example:

```
class MyList(list):

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'MyList({super().__repr__()})'


class MySet(set):

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'MySet({super().__repr__()})'
```

Note the `__repr__()` definitions are identical except for the initial string prefix.  But when I print them, I get different results:

```
ml = MyList('abc')
print(ml) # MyList(['a', 'b', 'c'])

ms = MySet('abc')
print(ms) # MySet(MySet({'c', 'a', 'b'}))
```

The display of `MyList` is what I would expect.  But for some reason `MySet` is printed twice, as if the `__repr__` is being called recursively or something.  Does anyone know what's going on, or how best to get it to show `MySet({'c', 'a', 'b'})`, instead of `MySet(MySet({'c', 'a', 'b'}))`?

**[Edit]**
As of 3.9.5, in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c function `set_repr` has the code:

```
    if (!PySet_CheckExact(so))
        result = PyUnicode_FromFormat("%s({%U})",
                                      Py_TYPE(so)->tp_name,
                                      listrepr);
    else
        result = PyUnicode_FromFormat("{%U}", listrepr);
```

In other words, `set` is hardcoded so that its `__repr__` omits the class name if the type is exactly a `set` and the set is non-empty, but shows the class name otherwise.  But `dict` and `list` don't do this, for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default print of `set`, it prints the class name. If you remove the `format` you added it comes out exactly as you wanted.

```
class MySet(set):

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return super().__repr__()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ms = MySet('abc')
    print(ms)
    MySet.__name__ = 'New_name'
    print(ms)
```

Oututput :

```py
MySet({'b', 'c', 'a'})
New_name({'b', 'c', 'a'})
```

Comment: `print(set.__name__) # set` `s1 = set('abc')` `print(s1) # {'a', 'c', 'b'}`
That is so odd...the base `set` doesn't print the class name but any subclass does?  And this behavior isn't consistent with `list` or `dict`... [Edit: Sorry don't know how to multi-line code in comments like this]

Comment: I think it's just because they are different object types, a `class` can be modified and inherit, but a `built-in/extension` can only be inherit and mostly are nameless, like a lambda. It may not be the reason but it could be.

Comment: I did some digging into the source code and found that this appears to be hardcoded.  Will update my original post and thanks for the help!